# x no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by, count

I am trying to count every id that corresponds to an unique id,
however the next error keeps arising.

Here's my code:

```
direct_reports <- data.frame(df %>% 
                                              group_by(manager_id) %>% 
                                              summarise(number_dr = 
                                               count(manager_id)) %>% 
                                 select(manager_id, number_dr))
```

Console output:

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `number_dr`.
x no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
i Input `number_dr` is `count(manager_id)`.
i The error occured in group 1: manager_id = 19292.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Hi, please consider adding a reproducible example of your data using `dput(df)`. Also, why do you put your pipeline into the `data.frame` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with `count` used inside the `summarise`.  It would be `n()` instead of `count`

```
library(dplyr)
 df  %>%
      group_by(manager_id) %>% 
      summarise(number_dr = n(), .groups = 'drop')
```

There is no need to `select` after the group by summarise step as the columns remaining are only 'manager_id' and 'number_dr'

---

`count` expects a `data.frame` or `tibble`

```
df %>%
    count(manager_id)
```